# How to redirect if route arguments are not passed?

Tags: flutter

I am not sure how to stop a screen or widget from loading when no arguments are passed. I have tried:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final GroupArguments args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
  if(args == null){

    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(GroupList.routeName);
  }
}
```

this just throws an error **setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.**

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: To call a function without affecting build, wrap It with [addPostFrameCallback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html).

Comment: @tokenyet This kinda works. It shows the error for a second or 2 then goes to the navigator. Is there a way to prevent this from going to far as to show red screen?

Comment: @JasonSpick I don't know what code you did, but you could try return `Container()` to prevent rendering error.

Comment: @Tokenyet Ok, so this just throws navigation into a loop

Answer (score 0):

This is a working solution on Flutter 2.2.3 using a custom static helper method called `checkRouteArg`

```
  static Widget? checkRouteArg(NavigatorState navigator, dynamic arg) {
    if (arg == null) {
      Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then((_) {
        navigator.pushReplacementNamed(TabScreen.routeName);
      });
      return Container();
    }

    return null;
  }
```

and on the widget itself something like this

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final navigator = Navigator.of(context);
  final arg = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as Playlist?;
  final check = Utils.checkRouteArg(navigator, arg);
  if (check != null) return check;

  final playlist = arg as Playlist;
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        child: SomeCustomWidget(playlist),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```